# I am trying to search for a file in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Code i used is:

```
List<ScenarioModel> result = new List<ScenarioModel>();

string webUrl = "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/ABCD/EFGHI";

string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"];

SecureString password = ConvertToSecureString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userPassword"]);

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
    ctx.Load(docList);

    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(ctx);
    keywordQuery.QueryText = queryText;

    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);

    ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
    {
        ScenarioModel modelObject = new ScenarioModel();
        modelObject.Path = resultRow["Path"];
        modelObject.Title = resultRow["Title"].ToString();
        result.Add(modelObject);
    }
}

return result;
```

Now this returns me the correct path. When I click on url, I am asked to download that one note file. Is there a way in which i can open this sharepoint file online instead of downloading it?

Comment: What type of files are you listing?

Comment: I am searching for one note files

Comment: Try this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finded this way

```
ctx.Load(item.File);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(item.File.LinkingUrl);
```

LikingUrl is what you want I thinks.

Comment: Thanks @Mary. This is what i was looking for.